# lucene boolean search

Tags: algorithm, search, lucene, match, booleanquery

I want to know how lucene find documents matching a [boolean query](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) like this: `"+a +b c"`, I mean what's its algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at the Lucene source, docs or posting to the mailing list

Answer (score 1):

1. [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)
2. [Lucene Theory](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/09/lucene-performance.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Apache Lucene - Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html). It helped me to understand the algorithm

- "+a +b c" means that you are searching for documents that MUST contain "a" AND MUST contain "b" and MIGHT contain "c" --> For example the matches are: "**b a**", "**a b c**", "wkfkjwfk32 **a b**", "kj2h4rkj2 **a** kjhgkk **b**" in any order [**a** and **b** are required, and **c** is optional]